# How do I programmatically install a certificate to the windows personal certificate store using Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, jca

[image]
In the windows personal certificate store, I am trying to programmatically install a certificate with the private key(using method setKeyEntry) using Java. But I get an exception when I do that.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot assign the key to the given alias.
    at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(CKeyStore.java:405)
    at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CKeyStore$MY.engineSetKeyEntry(CKeyStore.java:57)
```

Code snippet:

```
    KeyStore userCertStore = KeyStore.getInstance(getValue(CERTIFICATE_STORE_TYPE));
    userCertStore.load(null,null);
    for (iaik.x509.X509Certificate cert : user.getUserCertificates()) {
        userCertStore.setCertificateEntry(cert.getSubjectDN().toString(), cert);
        userCertStore.setKeyEntry(cert.getSubjectDN().toString(),user.getUserPrivateKey(cert),new 
        SecureStringBuffer(new StringBuffer(password)).toCharArray(),user.getUserCertificates());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificates are already set during `setKeyEntry` - do not store the certificate using `setCertificateEntry`.

`setCertificateEntry` is used to set *trusted certificates* (of the other party), the `setKeyEntry` is used to store private keys and the full certificate chain belonging to that private key.

So when you set the private key the alias is already taken by a "trusted certificate".

Comment: As I didn't test this myself (just applied reasoning), please comment below if this fixed your issue (I presume it did through the accept, but yeah, just want to be sure).